# How to give different output for each Linux distro

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to check for different distros and Use that for using different outputs, for example, if it checks and detects a Debian output is "systemctl reboot -i" and if it detects kali it changes to "reboot"

my problem is not being able to detect the operating system and give the necessary output for each distro, for example, the small differences in system commands for debian11, Ubuntu, kali, and arch.

I have tried using an if statement but haven't been able to get it to work, probably because of my lack of experience.So if any one has a solution pls help me

[full code](https://github.com/AROA-DEV/automator/blob/Beta-testing/automator.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

RED="\e[31m"
GREEN="\e[32m"
YELOW="\e[33m"  
BLUE="\e[34m"
ENDCOLOR="\e[0m";
echo 
echo 
echo _█████╗_██╗___██╗████████╗_██████╗_███╗___███╗_█████╗_████████╗_██████╗_██████╗ 
echo ██╔══██╗██║___██║╚══██╔══╝██╔═══██╗████╗_████║██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗
echo ███████║██║___██║___██║___██║___██║██╔████╔██║███████║___██║___██║___██║██████╔╝
echo ██╔══██║██║___██║___██║___██║___██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║___██║___██║___██║██╔══██╗
echo ██║__██║╚██████╔╝___██║___╚██████╔╝██║_╚═╝_██║██║__██║___██║___╚██████╔╝██║__██║
echo ╚═╝__╚═╝ ╚═════╝____╚═╝____╚═════╝ ╚═╝_____╚═╝╚═╝__╚═╝___╚═╝____╚═════╝_╚═╝__╚═╝
echo 
uptime
who
echo
if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "${RED}!!! run as root !!!${ENDCOLOR}"
    echo -e "${RED} or a user with the permisions ${ENDCOLOR}"
    sleep 5
fi
echo
echo
echo -e compleate system setup "${YELOW}[systemsetup]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e update "${YELOW}[update]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e install Osint tools "${YELOW}[1]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e install Exploit tools "${YELOW}[2]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e install Wireles tools "${YELOW}[3]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e install vulnerability detection tools "${YELOW}[4]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e test network "${YELOW}[network]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e show options "${YELOW}[op]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e show version "${YELOW}[v]${ENDCOLOR}"
echo 
while true; do
read -p "how do you want to proceed? " yn

case $yn in 

# simple uptions output

    system ) echo ;
             echo system tools ;
             echo ;
             echo -e show system info "${YELOW}[sinfo]${ENDCOLOR}";
             echo ;
             echo -e create user "${YELOW}[newuser]${ENDCOLOR}";
             echo -e remuve user "${YELOW}[remuveuser]${ENDCOLOR}";
             echo ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `/etc/os-release` file contains all information you need. You can `cat`, `grep`, ... for getting all relevant information.

Comment: The format of `/etc/os-release` [was deliberately designed](https://www.linux.org/docs/man5/os-release.html) to be sourced as a shell script. So you could just do `source /etc/os-release` and access the variables directly.

Comment: I have tried using `cat /etc/issue #check distro
read distro
if [ $distro -eq Debian ]
then
        echo "You are using Debian"
else
        echo "you are not using Debian some things may not work"
fi`

Comment: but ill try your recomenndations

Comment: its giving me these error `./test.sh: line 28: [: -eq: unary operator expected`